# How can I troubleshoot design-time packages in Delphi/C++Builder?

Tags: delphi, components, c++builder

I have consistently had IDE problems in Delphi/C++Builder for years, with every version.  I usually just reboot, recompile, etc. and move on.  However, I keep seeing others say that the IDE is rock solid.  I've read many people say that most IDE problems are a result of custom component problems.

We have several of our own custom components and I would not be at all surprised that they were causing the problems.  However, I have no idea how to find out.

1) I cannot easily just uninstall a component and see how things go.  Each component is vital to our project and designing it out so I can test for a few days is not practical.
2) When I have IDE crashes, they are usually AV's with little (to me) useful information.
3) Sometimes the IDE works for hours with no problems.  There are no reasonably reproducible issues, just seemingly random crashes, AV's and failed compiles.

Has anyone had any luck troubleshooting design-time packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.gexperts.org/faq.html/#crashes) is how to debug an expert (GExperts in this case). This should be transferrable to your case.

Comment: Thanks, this was also useful to step into a runtime package that I was testing via DUnit GUI test runner. Made the package project active and set for Host application the test project executable